# Adobe Android ANE support armeabi

Tags: android, air, adobe, ane, twilio-video

I am integrating Twilio video in android with my adobe air app. I can successfully add video sdk in ane but twilio video sdk uses com.getkeepsafe.relinker SDK.

This SDK gives me below error

```
Process: air.TestApp, PID: 585
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{air.TestApp/com.nethram.video.views.MainActivity}: com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: lib/armeabi/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2456)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:159)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: com.getkeepsafe.relinker.MissingLibraryException: lib/armeabi/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so
   at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ApkLibraryInstaller.installLibrary(ApkLibraryInstaller.java:85)
   at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibraryInternal(ReLinkerInstance.java:180)
   at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinkerInstance.loadLibrary(ReLinkerInstance.java:136)
   at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:70)
   at com.getkeepsafe.relinker.ReLinker.loadLibrary(ReLinker.java:51)
   at com.twilio.video.MediaFactory.instance(MediaFactory.java:47)
   at com.twilio.video.LocalAudioTrack.create(LocalAudioTrack.java:98)
   at com.twilio.video.LocalAudioTrack.create(LocalAudioTrack.java:75)
   at com.nethram.video.views.MainActivity.createAudioAndVideoTracks(MainActivity.java:260)
   at com.nethram.video.views.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:131)
   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6304)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2409)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2539) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:159) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1384) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

When I look into this error, I think this package uses armeabi split.

Is there any method to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you packaged the jni native libraries with your extension? ie the `so` files in a libs/armeabi directory?

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I didn't added jni files. Just copying so files to android/libs directory is enough?

Comment: @Michael Solved the issue after adding jni files to lib. Thank you. Please write down your solution as answer

Comment: Glad it was a simple fix.

Comment: Yeah! Can't find any documentation on this.

Comment: Yeah must say I spent many hours trying different things before I completely understood what AIR does here. Still it's amazingly powerful that we can include this sort of implementation relatively easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When packaging an ANE that uses an SDK that relies on native (jni) libraries you need to ensure they are also included in your ANE package. These must be placed in the `libs` directory in the appropriate architecture directory (`armeabi` etc).

If dealing with an `aar` file, then you can simply check if it contains a `jni` directory and copy it's contents to the `libs` directory in your ANE platform implementation.

You should end up with the following structure:

```
[ANDROID_PLATFORM]/
    your_ane_implementation.jar
    your_ane_res/
    libs/
        armeabi/
            libXXXXX.so
        armeabi-v7a/
            libXXXXX.so    
        ...
```